# find pixel that is closest to the corners

Tags: python, numpy

I have a following problem. I would like to find non-empty pixels coordinares that are closest to the left down corner and upper right corder, respectivelly.

This function returns upper left and down right coordinates and I cannot figure out why:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_corner_pixels(img):
    # Get image dimensions
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    
    left_down = (height-1, width-1)
    upper_right = (0, 0)

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            #  non-black
            if not np.array_equal(img[i,j], [0,0,0]):
                
                if (i + j) < (left_down[0] + left_down[1]):
                    left_down = (i, j)
                
                if (i + j) > (right_up[0] + right_up[1]):
                    right_up = (i, j)

    return left_down, right_up
```

Can you help me to find the mistake, please?

The output is obviously wrong, see picture with red dots that should denote the corner:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that your corners are the wrong way around. I reckon these would work:

```
left_down = (width-1, 0)
upper_right = (0, height-1)
```

I'm kind of confused as to what these conditionals are for. Are you comparing the added coordinates of the pixels and comparing them to the added coordinates of the corner?

```
if (i + j) < (left_down[0] + left_down[1]):
    left_down = (i, j)
                
if (i + j) > (right_up[0] + right_up[1]):
    right_up = (i, j)
```

This is the only thing that makes sense to do, checking if

```
if i < left_down[0] and j > left_down[1]):
    left_down = (i, j)
                
if i < right_up[0] and j > right_up[1]:
    right_up = (i, j)
```

This should check if the found pixels are either lower and more left from the top right corner and higher and more right from the bottom left corner.

If this was not your intention, you should more clearly describe what you mean by "closest to the corner".

Comment: Thanks. left_down = (width-1, 0) and upper_right = (0, height-1) are not correct, you are right. I am not checking coordinates correctly, you are right. Maybe euclidean distance might be better?

Comment: Euclidean distance would work, but you would have to find a method to determine the closest point to the corner by keeping some sort of record distance, and I would recommend a sort of bound from where to look so you don't have to go over every pixel of the image.